# Power Automate Desktop schedule

Tags: padding, power-automate

I have a premium version of Power Automate.
I'd like to set a schedule in Power Automate Desktop and I know that it have to be done by Power Automate in browser.
I need to refresh flows at night.

Can I do this on my TURN OFF laptop at night?
Or I need some virtual machine or sth like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create one flow in power automate browser and call your desktop flow.
To trigger the flow automatically you can set some trigger for example if file is added/uploaded in sharepoint or onedrive, mail is received from any specific sender with particular subject, file is uploaded in BOX.com. This way you can achieve automatic trigger of your desktop flow.

Answer (score 0):

Power Automate Desktop flows run on the computer itself, so yes, you will either need a virtual machine with the Power Automate Desktop runtime installed on it, connected to your Cloud Environment. Or you can schedule a Power Automate Desktop flow to run on your computer with Task Scheduler. You will need to have you computer left on for it to run.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/run-desktop-flows-url-shortcuts#trigger-flows-automatically-with-task-scheduler